# Remove padding from GridView and use the entire view to put items

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-imageview, android-gridview

I am trying to use `GridView` as a base for a simple snake and ladder game. Currently I have 16 cells and I want this 16 cells fill up the entire screen (the gridview is the only view in the xml file.

Here is the layout_game.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="384px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="64px"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Next I have the implementation of the BaseAdapter, the `getView` is like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(_context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(64,64));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(_cellIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

For my drawables, I have images which are originally 256 by 256 pixels. What I Want is 16 cells to fill the width of the screen, and I dont mind the number of rows I just want it to look fullscreen. With my current code I got the following result...and its awful! please share your expirience with me.

**So what I would like to know is:**

- How to get rid of the withe padding or border between images so they sit next to eachother
- How to programatically find out the size I should use in `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(64,64));` so that only 6 image sit in a row

[image]

**UPDATE**

I figured out the problem with the white borders between images are caused by these params:

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

Setting it to `0dp` took care of that. Now only problem is to how to figure out the programatically way to calculate how many images will fill the `width` of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="384px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Make them `Match_Parent`,and the same goes for the child imageViews

Comment: That didnt help, the with border between images is still there and only now I have more images in a row. I want to have 6 images in each row so they fully populate the view atleast width-wise

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with the white borders between images are caused by these params:

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

Setting it to `0dp` took care of that. Now only problem is to how to figure out the programatically way to calculate how many images will fill the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `numColumns="auto_fit"` should take care of calculating how many images will fill the width of the screen. The only reason it is not doing it now is because the width of your `GridView` is set to `384px` instead of `match_parent`. Then you can just receive the number of columns by calling `gridView.getNumColumns()`.